# Any plans for "do"/Action LINQ operator?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

Here's a simple method with a `foreach` loop:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> FieldsToXElements(object instance)
{
    var fieldElements = new List<XElement>();

    foreach (var field in instance.GetType().GetFields(instance))
    {
        fieldElements.Add(new XElement(field.Name, field.GetValue(instance)));
    }

    return fieldElements;
}
```

Kind of ugly. If there were some operator in LINQ that mean "do something" (e.g. perform an `Action` for each selected in the LINQ statement), it would look nicer, more terse:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> FieldsToXElements(object instance)
{
    var fieldElements = new List<XElement>();

    from field in instance.GetType().GetFields(instance))
    let name = field.Name
    let value = field.GetValue(instance)
    do fieldElements.Add(new XElement(name, value));

    return fieldElements;
}
```

I realize that's subjective, and just my opinion. For a foreach loop that has one line that simply invokes a method, a "`do`" operator makes sense, in my opinion. **But I'm wondering if anyone at MS has thought the same thing. Is such LINQ operator planned in any upcoming releases (e.g. alongside the C# 4.0 debut)?**

Here's another example, with a predicate, where the fictitious `do` operator would really make the code look cleaner. This:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> FieldsToXElements
    (object instance, Func<FieldInfo, bool> predicate)
{
    var fieldElements = new List<XElement>();

    foreach (var field in instance.GetType().GetFields(instance).Where(predicate))
    {
        fieldElements.Add(new XElement(field.Name, field.GetValue(instance)));
    }

    return fieldElements;
}
```

vs. this:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> FieldsToXElements
    (object instance, Func<FieldInfo, bool> predicate)
{
    var fieldElements = new List<XElement>();

    from field in instance.GetType().GetFields(instance))
    let name = field.Name
    let value = field.GetValue(instance)
    where predicate(field)
    do fieldElements.Add(new XElement(name, value));

    return fieldElements;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, I don't expect any direct **language** suport (i.e. inside the query syntax) any time soon.

It sounds like you mean the mythical `ForEach` extension method; trivial to add, but Eric Lippert has commented numerous times about the cross between side-effect-free functional code and `Action<T>` with side-effects. In particular, C# 3.0 / .NET 3.5 expression trees are lousy at side-effecs (making full lambda support tricky). The runtime side [is much better in .NET 4.0](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/11/future-expressions.html), but it is unclear at the moment how much of this will make it into the language (lambda compiler) in C# 4.0.

All you need (for delegate version) is:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{   // note: omitted arg/null checks
    foreach(T item in source) { action(item); }
}
```

Then from any query you can simply use `.ForEach(x => /* do something */)`.

Answer (score 3):

For your specific example (populating a `List<XElement>`), I'd do it this way.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> FieldsToXElements(object instance)
{
  List<XElement> fieldElements =
  (
    from field in instance.GetType().GetFields(instance))
    let name = field.Name
    let value = field.GetValue(instance)
    select new XElement(name, value)
  ).ToList();  //Another Option is List<T>.AddRange()
  return fieldElements;
}
```

Also: Don't forget that `List<T>` already implements `.ForEach<T>()`, so to use it against any `Enumerable<T>`, this is all the code you need.

```
myEnumerable.ToList().ForEach( x => myAction(x) );
```

Comment: Very nice! Didn't think of that. Although I would shorten it slightly by just doing: return (from field in...).ToList() without defining List<XElement> fieldElements. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is too hard or maybe I'm missing something...

```
IEnumerable<XElement> FieldsToXElements(object instance)
{
    return instance.GetType()
                   .GetFields(instance)
                   .Select( f => new XElement( f.Name,
                                               f.GetValue(instance) ) );
}
```

Comment: The task is trivial. I'm more interested in the "prettiness" of the code. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply looking at calling a function from within your linq statement then you can already do that, you can make a call out to a function in a Let assignment.

```
var qry = from e in somelist
          let errorcode = DoSomeProcessing(e)
          select e;
```

Comment: The only problem here is DoSomeProcessing is a Func<>, not an Action<> :)